# How to add an automatic adornment at the beginning of every margin note?

Tags: marginpar

When the following LaTeX code, which is saved in the file `~/Test.tex`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]\marginpar{\lipsum[2-2][1-1]}
\end{document}
```

is compiled by executing the following commands in the Terminal

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

the resulting `~/Test.pdf`, when opened in a PDF viewer, looks thusly (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display):

[image: A bare margin note.]

---

**Question**

How can I make every margin note start automatically with a triangle (package `amssymb`'s `\blacktriangleright`, which requires math mode), as in the following screenshot?

[image: A margin note with an adornment]

Notes:

1. The margin note is to be set to the right of the triangle, as opposed to the triangle being embedded in the margin note as though it were the first letter thereof.
2. The triangle's baseline should align with that of the top line of the margin note.
3. There should be a little horizontal space between the triangle and the margin note's bounding box, say an `\enspace`.
4. I'm fine with using another type of margin note than the built-in `\marginpar`, if there is some package that makes my objective easy to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on modifying `\marginpar`, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newlength{\blacktrianglerightwidth}
\settowidth{\blacktrianglerightwidth}{$\blacktriangleright$}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@savemarbox#1#2{%
\global\setbox #1\color@vbox\vtop{%
\hsize\marginparwidth\@parboxrestore
\@marginparreset $\blacktriangleright$\hskip.5em\relax
\begin{minipage}[t]{%
\dimexpr\marginparwidth-\blacktrianglerightwidth-.5em}#2%
\end{minipage}%
\par\@minipagefalse\outer@nobreak}\color@endbox
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-1]\marginpar{\lipsum[2-2][1-1]}
\end{document}
```

But I think it would be better to define your own command, say `\mymarginpar` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newlength{\blacktrianglerightwidth}
\settowidth{\blacktrianglerightwidth}{$\blacktriangleright$}


\newcommand\mymarginpar[1]{%
    \marginpar{%
        $\blacktriangleright$\hskip.5em\relax
        \begin{minipage}[t]{%
                \dimexpr\marginparwidth-\blacktrianglerightwidth-.5em}#1%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
}



\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-1]\mymarginpar{\lipsum[2-2][1-1]}
\end{document}
```

The output pdf for both is
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. One note: the code you wrote in the preambles should be encapsulated in an `\AtBeginDocument` hook, or else it may not compile. See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670064/21685) and the comments thereto.

Comment: @EvanAad, the post you linked has a different preamble, I wasn't considering any math font changes. Note that you only need to enclose the line `\settowidth{\blacktrianglerightwidth}{$\blacktriangleright$}` with `\AtBeginDocument`, anything else should be ok.