# How to access a unicode-math symbol in the preamble?

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, preamble, stix2

**A demonstration of the problem by way of a minimal working example**

I saved the following LaTeX code in the file `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\newlength{\mytrianglewidth}
\begin{document}
\settowidth{\mytrianglewidth}{$\smallblacktriangleright$}
\the\mytrianglewidth
\end{document}
```

The code creates a document of class `article`. It loads the *STIX Two Math* font, which makes available, among others, the command `\smallblacktriangleright`. It then creates a new length variable called `\mytrianglewidth`. Inside the document's body it initializes the length variable to the width of the glyph associated with the `\smallblacktriangleright` command. Finally, it prints out the value of the length variable.

I then executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

The compilation completed successfully, and resulted in the creation of the file `~/Test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed the string `6.76pt`.

So far so good. I now moved the command `\settowidth` to the end of the preamble, and recompiled. The compilation failed, and `~/Test.log` contained the following message.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \smallblacktriangleright 
                         
l.7 ...\mytrianglewidth}{$\smallblacktriangleright$}
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
<recently read> \smallblacktriangleright 
                         
l.7 ...\mytrianglewidth}{$\smallblacktriangleright$}
                                                  
End of file on the terminal!
```

**Question**

Is there a way to access the values of the commands provided by the *STIX Two Math* font in the preamble, without this resulting in a compilation failure?

**Motivation**

The reason for this wish is so I can define commands, such as the `\mymarginpar` command proposed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669696/21685).

**A possible solution**

One way to solve this problem is by passing the `\settowidth` command to the `\AtBeginDocument` hook, thus:

```
...
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\mytrianglewidth}{$\smallblacktriangleright$}}
\begin{document}
...
```

This works, but feels like cheating, since the value of `\smallblacktriangleright` is not truly accessed in the preamble. I wonder if there are other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: you shouldn't do "typesetting" in the preamble as fonts are not fully set up yet. Using \AtBeginDocument is the right thing to to.

Comment: it's not cheating: you just need atbegindocument to match unicode-math which delays all its definitions using  atbegindocument

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was self-answered in an edit.